# Confused by RefererDeniedMapError

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the Google Maps Javascript Geocoder code.  I figured I'd start with their example at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

I copied their code exactly, putting in my Browser Key where it said YOUR_API_KEY,
and the page seems to load for a moment, and then I get this error in my console:

> Google Maps API error: RefererDeniedMapError

And a Javascript alert telling me that it was unable to load.

I have checked my developer console and I have enabled the Google Maps JavaScript API, and I don't have any referrers set up for that key (which is supposed to let all requests through), and yet I still get this error.

I have to believe I still have a setting wrong somewhere, but the console is so simple to use I can't identify where.  Can anyone give me the benefits of their experiences on setting up the Browser key to work properly?

Thanks in advance,

DW

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for the downvote.  I'm only asking because Google's docs are sub-optimal and they herd everyone here for support.  No need to get nasty....

Comment: I have upvoted your question back to zero, as I see nothing wrong with it!

Comment: @Joel Thanks for that!

Comment: Seems like a bug https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8212